# How to fix: Notice: Array to string conversion error when I try to compress images based on an array

Tags: php

Hi I need help with my code please. I was trying to compress images on an array but I received an error called "Notice: Array to string conversion" and I don't know how tho solve it I guess that the var $location could be the problem...

I attached my code and the problematic line is:

`$location = $carpeta.$_FILES['imagen']['name'];`

```
<?php

/*CREATE A FOLDER TO INSERT THE IMAGES*/

$carpeta = "../img/posts/".$tipo_post."/".$fecha_post." - ".$encabezado_post."/";
$carpeta_bd = "img/posts/".$tipo_post."/".$fecha_post." - ".$encabezado_post."/";

if (!file_exists($carpeta)) {
    mkdir($carpeta, 0777, true);
}

/*IT'S TIME TO INSERT THE IMAGES*/

$imagenes_a_contar = $_FILES['imagen']['name']; //COUNTING IMAGES
$contador_imagenes = count($imagenes_a_contar);

for ($i = 0; $i < ($contador_imagenes); ++$i) {
    $nombre_imagen_normal = $_FILES["imagen"]["name"];
    $nombre_imagen_tmp = $_FILES["imagen"]["tmp_name"];

    /*TRYING TO COMPRESS THE IMAGES BEFORE TO SAVE THEM*/

    $valid_ext = array('png', 'jpeg', 'jpg');

    $location = $carpeta.$_FILES['imagen']['name'];

    // GET THE FILE EXTENSION
    $file_extension = pathinfo($location, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $file_extension = strtolower($file_extension);

    // CHECK THE EXTENSION TO START THE COMPRESSION
    if (in_array($file_extension, $valid_ext)) {
        $location_2 = $carpeta.$_FILES['imagen']['name'].$file_extension;

        // COMPRESSING IMAGES
        compressImage($_FILES["imagen"]["name"], $location_2, 60);
    }

    /*SAVING IMAGES INTO THE DIRECTORY AND THE DATABASE*/

    //$url_imagen_normal[$i] = $carpeta.$nombre_imagen_normal[$i];
    $url_imagen_bd[$i] = $carpeta_bd.$nombre_imagen_normal[$i];
    @copy($nombre_imagen_tmp[$i], $url_imagen_normal[$i]);
    mysqli_query($conexion_post, "INSERT INTO imagenes VALUES('','$codigo_post','$url_imagen_bd[$i]','1')");
}

/*-------------------------------------*/

/*FUNCTION TO COMPRESS IMAGES*/

function compressImage($source, $destination, $quality) {
    $info = getimagesize($source);

    if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') {
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
    } elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') {
        $image = imagecreatefromgif($source);
    } elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') {
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($source);
    }

    imagejpeg($image, $destination, $quality);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's a mess but probably `$location = $carpeta.$_FILES['imagen']['name'][$i];`

Comment: Hi. I updated that line of code but the error persists.

Comment: This issue is all through the code, would be better off using `foreach ($_FILES["imagen"]["name"] as $key => $name) {` then use `$key` to access the other parts like `tmp_name` etc.

Comment: _Hi. I updated that line of code but the error persists._ No, it's at a different line.

Comment: I added the foreach but the error persits